# Объединить строки

Tags: python, pandas, csv, обработка-данных

Есть файл csv:

```
0,10,15,14
0,12,17,17
1,14,19,15
1,11,12,13
```

Я его считываю, и даю названия колонкам

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['name' + str(i) for i in range(3)])
res = dataset.groupby("name0").agg("??")
res_dict = res.T.to_dict("list")
```

Как мне его сгруппировать чтобы я получил:

```
x = {
    "0": [[10, 15, 14], [12, 17, 17]],
    "1": [[14, 19, 15], [11, 12, 13]]
    }
```

Не обязательно через `groupby`, можно взять уникальные значения - 0 и 1, и сделать по ним выборку. Но я не знаю как.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None).add_prefix("name")

res = [{a: b.drop(columns="name0").to_numpy().tolist()} for a,b in df.groupby("name0")]
```

результат:

```
In [109]: res
Out[109]: [{0: [[10, 15, 14], [12, 17, 17]]}, {1: [[14, 19, 15], [11, 12, 13]]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Python - прекрасный язык, вы можете в качестве аггрегатора указать даже коллекцию:

```
dataset.groupby("name0").agg(list)
```

Хотя это не весь ответ, на выходе будет DataFrame, в словарь ещё нужно будет перевести.

Comment: что-то я не представляю как получить ожидаемый результат из этого ответа ;)

Comment: @MaxU Дайте свой ответ, правильный )  Хотя не знаю, может автору на самом деле словарь и не нужен, как знать )

Comment: @CrazyElf  нуу вообще да, то что надо, но я уже по другому сделал

Comment: я свой ответ привел, но он мне не очень нравится :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv

d = {}

with open("dataset.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for line in reader:
        k, v = line[0], line[1:]
        d[k] = d.setdefault(k, []) + [v]

print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
res={}
[res.setdefault(str(x[0]),[]).append(list(x[1:])) for x in data.values]
```

res:

```
{'0': [[10, 15, 14], [12, 17, 17]], '1': [[14, 19, 15], [11, 12, 13]]}
```